# using perforce with team foundation server

Tags: tfs, integration, perforce

Does Team Foundation Server 2008 or upcoming 2010 work with perforce as the SCM tool? I haven't been able to find any documentation on the web indicating whether or not this configuration is supported? I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: What do you want to do? TFS has a repository, and Perforce is one. Do you want TFS to use the Perforce repository instead of it's own?

Comment: Has it changed ? TFS now supports git. So maybe it is possible to use Perforce as well ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not a supported configuration. TFS only works with TFS' own version control.

Answer (score 0):

We want to be able to utilize team build, lab management, test case management, and possibly defect/work item management. At the present time we are not interested in using TFS as the source code repository because we've made a big investment in perforce. Possibly in the future, we may shift from Perforce to TFS, just not right now.