# Using Perforce with TFS as a continuous integration server, is it possible?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, perforce

After using SVN as a VCS (we're a small dev team), we found it too hard to work with, and we switched to perforce in April. We're really happy with it, and we want to take it one step further by adding a Continuous Integration Server so that our builds are more reliable.
We have a MSDN licence allowing us to have TFS if we want (as a CI server), but we don't want to change what's already in place.

BUT, TFS has no native interactions with perforce, and vice versa. 
So my question is, does anyone know if it's actually possible?

I googled a bit, I found an answer posted in 2009 ([using perforce with team foundation server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745612/using-perforce-with-team-foundation-server)) saying it's not. But maybe it has changed since then...I didn't find any plugin or anything else to help me, and I need your help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct way to migrate Perforce to TFS.
However if you have got MSDN subscription, you could evaluate TFS for ALM/Build/Deployment.

Comment: Well, we chose to use Jenkins. Perfect integration with Perforce and Jira :)